# Select daily data group by weekly in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

hi friend i have following my table structure and data

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pairs_Details](
   [sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [userid] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [date] [datetime] NULL,
   [ljoin] [int] NULL,
   [rjoin] [int] NULL
       ) ON [PRIMARY]

sno userid          date                             ljoin  rjoin

1   LDS         2014-02-17 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
2   LDS         2014-02-17 00:00:00.000             NULL    1
3   LDS1        2014-02-18 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
4   LDS         2014-02-18 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
5   LDS1        2014-02-18 00:00:00.000              NULL   1
6   LDS         2014-02-18 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
7   SUNIL1      2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
8   LDS1        2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
9   LDS         2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1     NULL
10  SUNIL1      2014-02-19 00:00:00.000             NULL    1
11  LDS1       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000               1      NULL
12  LDS         2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1      NULL
13  SUNIL2     2014-02-19 00:00:00.000               1  NULL
14  LDS1          2014-02-19 00:00:00.000               NULL    1
15  LDS       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000                1      NULL
16  rajesh123  2014-02-19 00:00:00.000                   1  NULL
17  SUNIL1     2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
18  LDS1       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000               1        NULL
19  LDS      2014-02-19 00:00:00.000                  1       NULL
20  SUNIL2     2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
21  LDS1       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
22  LDS        2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1          NULL
23  LDS2       2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              1         NULL
24  LDS        2014-02-19 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
25  SUNIL1     2014-02-20 00:00:00.000                  NULL        1
26  LDS1       2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              1        NULL
27  LDS    2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              1         NULL
28  rajesh123  2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              NULL     1
29  SUNIL1     2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
30  LDS1       2014-02-20 00:00:00.000              1         NULL
31  LDS     2014-02-20 00:00:00.000             1   NULL
32  LDS    2014-02-24 00:00:00.000              NULL    1
33  Jitendra123 2014-02-27 00:00:00.000             1   NULL
34  LDS2            2014-02-27 00:00:00.000             1   NULL
35  LDS         2014-02-27 00:00:00.000             NULL    1
36  rajeev123   2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
37  Jitendra123 2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
40  jyoti123    2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
41  SUNIL1          2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
42  LDS1            2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
43  LDS         2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
44  meeta           2014-03-01 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
45  jyoti123    2014-03-01 00:00:00.000              1  NULL
46  SUNIL1   2014-03-01 00:00:00.000                 1  NULL
47  LDS1     2014-03-01 00:00:00.000                      1 NULL
48  LDS  2014-03-01 00:00:00.000              1 NULL
38  LDS2     2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              1 NULL
39  LDS  2014-02-27 00:00:00.000              NULL  1
```

**and this is my stored procdure .**

```
create proc [dbo].[pair_Scounting]
(
@userid nvarchar(50),
@start_date datetime,
@end_date datetime
)
as
begin
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SELECT  userid,
Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) AS ljoin,
Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) AS rjoin, DATEPART(wk, Date) AS WeekNumber,
CASE 
WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min([date])), Min([date]))) < YEAR(Min([date]))
THEN CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR, 0 ,GETDATE())), 0) AS Varchar(50))   + ' TO ' + Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min([date]))), Min([date]))  AS Varchar(50))
ELSE
Cast(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min([date])), Min([date])) AS Varchar(50)) + ' TO ' + Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min([date]))), Min([date]))  AS Varchar(50))
END  DateRange,
Case 
 When Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) > Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) Then Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0))-Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0))  
 End LeftCary,
 Case 
 When Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0)) > Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0)) Then Sum(ISNULL(rjoin,0))-Sum(ISNULL(ljoin,0))  
 End RightCary
FROM Pairs_Details  where  userid=@userid and date between @start_date and @end_date
Group By userid,DATEPART(wk, Date)
end
GO
```

if i execute my stored procedure as follows it return following result

exec pair_Scounting 'LDS','2014-02-17','2014-02-28'

```
 userid ljoin   rjoin   WeekNumber  DateRange           LeftCary     RightCary


 LDS    10        2       8   17-02-2014  TO 23-02-2014    8          NULL
 LDS    1         3       9   24-02-2014  TO 2-03-2014    NULL         2
```

so how we can add this LeftCary (8) with ljoin of next DateRange(24-02-2014 To 2-03-2014)and

RightCary(2)with rjoin of next DateRange(4-03-2014  TO 10-03-2014)

means here ljoin of DateRange(24-02-2014  TO 2-03-2014) is 1 and LeftCary of DateRange( 17-02-2014  TO 23-02-2014) is 8 so total ljoin of DateRange((24-02-2014  TO 2-03-2014)) is 8+1=9

My Desired result as follows

userid ljoin   rjoin   WeekNumber  DateRange           LeftCary     RightCary

```
 LDS    10        2       8   17-02-2014  TO 23-02-2014    8          NULL
 LDS    9         3       9   24-02-2014  TO 2-03-2014    NULL         2
```

please any one can suggest us how this can be done

thanks

Comment: Do you ever have duplicate WeekNumbers?

Comment: No I have No duplicate WeekNumbers?

Comment: this question is a duplicate / repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129493/select-daily-data-group-by-weekly-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the stored procedure into an inline table valued function instead and join it on itself. The following presumes that you won't have duplicate WeekNumbers:

```
SELECT    x.userid,
          (x.ljoin + ISNULL((SELECT y.LeftCarry FROM dbo.InLine(@param1, @param2, @param3) AS y WHERE y.WeekNumber = (x.WeekNumber - 1)), 0)) AS ljoin_carry,
          (x.rjoin + ISNULL((SELECT z.RightCarry FROM dbo.InLine(@param1, @param2, @param3) AS z WHERE z.WeekNumber = (x.WeekNumber - 1)), 0)) AS rjoin_carry,
          x.WeekNumber,
          x.DateRange,
          x.LeftCarry,
          x.RightCarry

FROM      dbo.InLine(@param1, @param2, @param3) AS x

ORDER BY  x.WeekNumber
```

Comment: dear nethy thanks for your valuable solution but your   query is not working properly when we execute it return following error 'Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@param1".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@param1".
'

Comment: Did you create the inline table valued function?

Comment: No I did not you create the inline table valued function

Comment: You can use the same internal code from your stored procedure, but you are creating a function and returning a table. You can view the syntax here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Comment: dear friends, i do not understand Inline  function please provide full query